# All values of a column is converted to NaN while sub- setting

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am learning `bokeh` and following [a tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-data-visualization-bokeh/#getting-your-figure-ready-for-data) from real python.

In a tutorial it subsets a standings data set to only two teams and produces the result below. I get the exact same result except my game won column is converted to `NaN`. Any idea, why it is behaving like that

```
west_top_2 = standings[(standings['teamAbbr'] == 'HOU') | (standings['teamAbbr'] == 'GS')]\
        .loc[:,['stDate','teamAbbr','gamewon']].sort_values(['teamAbbr','stDate'])

       stDate teamAbbr  gameWon
9   2017-10-17       GS        0
39  2017-10-18       GS        0
69  2017-10-19       GS        0
99  2017-10-20       GS        1
129 2017-10-21       GS        1
```

My output

```
    stDate       teamAbbr  gamewon
9   2017-10-17       GS      NaN
39  2017-10-18       GS      NaN
69  2017-10-19       GS      NaN
99  2017-10-20       GS      NaN
129 2017-10-21       GS      NaN
```

Comment: gamewon should be game**W**on ?

Comment: Ok. This is a really silly error. I should have double checked that before asking. Thank you.

Comment: Happens to the best of us !

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your statement, this is the correct one:

```
west_top_2 = (standings[
    (standings['teamAbbr'] == 'HOU') | (standings['teamAbbr'] == 'GS')
].loc[:, ['stDate', 'teamAbbr', 'gameWon']].sort_values(['teamAbbr','stDate']))
```

You have a parenthesis missing and a capital 'W'.